# Python Pexpect returns two different outputs

Tags: python, pexpect

I have used the below code to pass the password to my application. It gives different output.

```
import pexpect

child=pexpect.spawn("mycommand")
i=child.expect(["Password:",pexpect.EOF])
print "Content-type:text\html\n\n Success"+str(i)
```

First I executed in command line the i value return "0", then I executed through web browser it returns a value "1". I want to pass the password from my web application text box how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks
Jana

Comment: please indent code instead of wrapping it in html bold tags, and welcome to stackoverflow..

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `pexpect.spawn.expect` that you are printing out is the `index` of the string position in the stream. Being 0 or 1 doesn't say much about success.
But I notice you are not sending the password itself, you should use `child.sendline` to send your password after `expect` has finished.

Comment: @Jana: any progress on this?